# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.spotifyclone.exoplayer.MusicService: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have implemented music service in my spotifyclone android app but when I run project I am getting following exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.spotifyclone.exoplayer.MusicService: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3610)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:206)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1716)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Assertions.checkArgument(Assertions.java:39)
 at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager$Builder.<init>(PlayerNotificationManager.java:353)
 at com.example.spotifyclone.exoplayer.MusicNotificationManager.<init>(MusicNotificationManager.kt:33)
 at com.example.spotifyclone.exoplayer.MusicService.onCreate(MusicService.kt:71)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3598)
```

below my MusicService.kt

```
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat
import android.support.v4.media.MediaDescriptionCompat
import android.support.v4.media.MediaMetadataCompat
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat
import androidx.media.MediaBrowserServiceCompat
import com.example.spotifyclone.exoplayer.callbacks.MusicPlaybackPreparer
import com.example.spotifyclone.exoplayer.callbacks.MusicPlayerEventListener
import com.example.spotifyclone.exoplayer.callbacks.MusicPlayerNotificationListener
import com.example.spotifyclone.other.Constants.MEDIA_ROOT_ID
import com.example.spotifyclone.other.Constants.NETWORK_ERROR
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.mediasession.MediaSessionConnector
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.mediasession.TimelineQueueNavigator
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import javax.inject.Inject

private const val SERVICE_TAG = "MusicService"


@AndroidEntryPoint
class MusicService : MediaBrowserServiceCompat() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dataSourceFactory: DefaultDataSourceFactory

    @Inject
    lateinit var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer

    @Inject
    lateinit var firebaseMusicSource: FirebaseMusicSource

    private val serviceJob = Job()
    private val serviceScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + serviceJob)

    private lateinit var mediaSession: MediaSessionCompat
    private lateinit var mediaSessionConnector: MediaSessionConnector
    var isForegroundService = false
    private var curPlayingSong: MediaMetadataCompat? = null
    private lateinit var musicNotificationManager: MusicNotificationManager
    private var isPlayerInitialized = false
    private lateinit var musicPlayerEventListener: MusicPlayerEventListener

    companion object {
        var curSongDuration = 0L
            private set
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        serviceScope.launch {
            firebaseMusicSource.fetchMediaData()
        }
        val activityIntent = packageManager?.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)?.let {
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, it, 0)
        }

        mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(this, SERVICE_TAG).apply {
            setSessionActivity(activityIntent)
            isActive = true
        }

        sessionToken = mediaSession.sessionToken
        musicNotificationManager = MusicNotificationManager(
            this,
            mediaSession.sessionToken,
            MusicPlayerNotificationListener(this)
        ) {
            curSongDuration = exoPlayer.duration
        }

        val musicPlaybackPreparer = MusicPlaybackPreparer(firebaseMusicSource) {
            curPlayingSong = it
            preparePlayer(
                firebaseMusicSource.songs,
                it,
                true
            )
        }
        mediaSessionConnector = MediaSessionConnector(mediaSession)
        mediaSessionConnector.setPlaybackPreparer(musicPlaybackPreparer)
        mediaSessionConnector.setQueueNavigator(MusicQueueNavigator())
        mediaSessionConnector.setPlayer(exoPlayer)
        musicPlayerEventListener = MusicPlayerEventListener(this)
        exoPlayer.addListener(musicPlayerEventListener)
        musicNotificationManager.showNotification(exoPlayer)
    }

    private inner class MusicQueueNavigator : TimelineQueueNavigator(mediaSession) {
        override fun getMediaDescription(player: Player, windowIndex: Int): MediaDescriptionCompat {
            return firebaseMusicSource.songs[windowIndex].description
        }

    }

    private fun preparePlayer(
        songs: List<MediaMetadataCompat>,
        itemToPlay: MediaMetadataCompat?,
        playNow: Boolean

    ) {
        val curSongIndex = if (curPlayingSong == null) 0 else songs.indexOf(itemToPlay)
        exoPlayer.setMediaSource(firebaseMusicSource.asMediaSource(dataSourceFactory))
        exoPlayer.prepare()
        exoPlayer.seekTo(curSongIndex, 0L)
        exoPlayer.playWhenReady = playNow

    }

    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
        exoPlayer.stop()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        serviceScope.cancel()
        exoPlayer.removeListener(musicPlayerEventListener)
        exoPlayer.release()
    }

    override fun onGetRoot(
        clientPackageName: String,
        clientUid: Int,
        rootHints: Bundle?
    ): BrowserRoot? {
        return BrowserRoot(MEDIA_ROOT_ID, null)
    }

    override fun onLoadChildren(
        parentId: String,
        result: Result<MutableList<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>>
    ) {
        when (parentId) {
            MEDIA_ROOT_ID -> {
                val resultsSent = firebaseMusicSource.whenReady { isInitialized ->
                    if (isPlayerInitialized) {
                        result.sendResult(firebaseMusicSource.asMediaItems())
                        if (!isInitialized && firebaseMusicSource.songs.isNotEmpty()) {
                            preparePlayer(
                                firebaseMusicSource.songs,
                                firebaseMusicSource.songs[0],
                                false
                            )
                            isPlayerInitialized = true
                        }
                    } else {
                        mediaSession.sendSessionEvent(NETWORK_ERROR, null)
                        result.sendResult(null)

                    }

                }
                if (!resultsSent) {
                    result.detach()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

below my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.spotifyclone">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:name=".SpotifyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SpotifyClone"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <service android:name="com.example.spotifyclone.exoplayer.MusicService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

below MusicNotificationManager.kt

```
@SuppressLint("Range")
class MusicNotificationManager(
    private val context:Context,
    sessionToken:MediaSessionCompat.Token,
    notificationListener:PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener,
    private val newSongCallback:() -> Unit

) {
    private val notificationManager: PlayerNotificationManager

    init {
        val mediaController = MediaControllerCompat(context, sessionToken)

        notificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(
            context,
            NOTIFICATION_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID

        )
            .setChannelNameResourceId(R.string.notification_channel_name)
            .setChannelDescriptionResourceId(R.string.notification_channel_description)
            .setMediaDescriptionAdapter(DescriptionAdapter(mediaController))
            .setNotificationListener(notificationListener)
            .setSmallIconResourceId(R.drawable.ic_music)
            .build()

    }

    fun showNotification(player: Player) {
        notificationManager.setPlayer(player)
    }

    private inner class DescriptionAdapter(
        private val mediaController: MediaControllerCompat
    ) : PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter {

        override fun getCurrentContentTitle(player: Player): CharSequence {
            return mediaController.metadata.description.title.toString()
        }

        override fun createCurrentContentIntent(player: Player): PendingIntent? {
            return mediaController.sessionActivity
        }

        override fun getCurrentContentText(player: Player): CharSequence? {
            return mediaController.metadata.description.subtitle.toString()
        }

        override fun getCurrentLargeIcon(
            player: Player,
            callback: PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback
        ): Bitmap? {
            Glide.with(context).asBitmap()
                .load(mediaController.metadata.description.iconUri)
                .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    override fun onResourceReady(
                        resource: Bitmap,
                        transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
                    ) {
                        callback.onBitmap(resource)
                    }

                    override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) = Unit
                })
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

what I have done rebuild invalidate cache and restart  and  followed allstackoverflow answers
I want to know where exactly I am making mistake what I have to do avoid crash in my app

Comment: The stacktrace suggests that one (or more) argument that is passed to the `MusicNotificationManager` is illegal. You might want to post the code of  `MusicNotificationManager` as the error happened on the line 33 in that file.

Comment: @sweak I have posted MusicNotificationManager code please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace mentions the **line 353** in the `PlayerNotificationManager` source code:

```
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager$Builder.<init>(PlayerNotificationManager.java:353)
```

Here is exactly that line (You can find the source code on [github](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/ab4d37f499ba49bb3cac7938eb03ebf7133ccfe6/library/ui/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerNotificationManager.java#L353)):

```java
checkArgument(notificationId > 0);
```

As You can see, the library checks if the `NOTIFICATION_ID` that You're passing is greater than 0. The solution is to change the definition of `NOTIFICATION_ID` to an integer greater than 0. Good luck with the projet :)

Comment: can you check my other post as well